# Collapsing Rows in R based on similarities in 2 columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am relatively new to R and I am having trouble merging rows based on similarities in multiple columns. 
I have the following dataset

```
LAST_NAME   FIRST_NAME  INTERVAL    VISIT_DATE  MFQ_1   MFQ_2   MFQ_3   Handedness  ARI_1   ARI_2   ARI_4   ARI_COMPLETED_BY
Doe Jane    Interval 1  1/1/99  4   6   2   Na  Na  Na  Na  Na
Doe Jane    Interval 1  1/1/99  Na  Na  Na  Right-Handed    Na  Na  Na  Na
Doe Jane    Interval 1  1/1/99  Na  Na  Na  Na  4   2   2   Dad
Doe Jane    Interval 2  2/4/04  Na  Na  Na  Right-Handed    Na  Na  Na  Na
Doe Jane    Interval 2  2/4/04  5   6   3   Na  Na  Na  Na  Na 
Doe Jane    Interval 2  2/4/04  Na  Na  Na  Na  4   5   5   Mom
Smith   Joe Interval 1  3/1/01  5   1   7   Na  Na  Na  Na  Na
Smith   Joe Interval 1  3/1/01  Na  Na  Na  Left-Handed Na  Na  Na  Na
Smith   Joe Interval 1  3/1/01  Na  Na  Na  Na  8   8   2   Dad
Smith   Joe Interval 2  5/4/09  Na  Na  Na  Na  8   5   4   Dad
Smith   Joe Interval 2  5/4/09  7   2   8   Na  Na  Na  Na  Na
Smith   Joe Interval 2  5/4/09  Na  Na  Na  Left-Handed Na  Na  Na  Na
```

and I would like to merge the rows based on Name/Interval/Date so that it looks like this:

```
LAST_NAME   FIRST_NAME  INTERVAL    VISIT_DATE  MFQ_1   MFQ_2   MFQ_3   Handedness  ARI_1   ARI_2   ARI_4   ARI_COMPLETED_BY
Doe Jane    Interval 1  1/1/99  4   6   2   Right-Handed    4   2   2   Dad
Doe Jane    Interval 2  2/4/04  5   6   3   Right-Handed    4   5   5   Mom
Smith   Joe Interval 1  3/1/01  5   1   7   Left-Handed 8   8   2   Dad
Smith   Joe Interval 2  5/4/09  7   2   8   Left-Handed 8   5   4   Dad
```

I have tried the following code:

```
CTDB %>% group_by(LAST_NAME:VISIT_DATE) %>% summarise_all(funs(na.omit(.)))
```

But I get the following errors

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: NA/NaN argument.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In LAST_NAME:VISIT_DATE :
  numerical expression has 3326 elements: only the first used
2: In LAST_NAME:VISIT_DATE :
  numerical expression has 3326 elements: only the first used
3: In evalq(LAST_NAME:VISIT_DATE, <environment>) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
4: In evalq(LAST_NAME:VISIT_DATE, <environment>) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

I'm not sure how to solve this to get the desired result. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work :( It ran without error, but popped out the exact same data frame

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to get it to work!!

Comment: Moving my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by_at` with `vars(...)`. (Note that `na.omit` does not do what you think it does. `na.exclude` is closer to what you wanted). If your values are actually `NA`, then you can use `i[!is.na(i)]` instead.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by_at(vars(LAST_NAME:VISIT_DATE)) %>% 
  summarise_all(function(i) { i[i!="Na"] })

df <- read.table(text="LAST_NAME   FIRST_NAME  INTERVAL    VISIT_DATE  MFQ_1   MFQ_2   MFQ_3   Handedness  ARI_1   ARI_2   ARI_4   ARI_COMPLETED_BY
Doe Jane    Interval_1  1/1/99  4   6   2   Na  Na  Na  Na  Na
Doe Jane    Interval_1  1/1/99  Na  Na  Na  Right-Handed    Na  Na  Na  Na
Doe Jane    Interval_1  1/1/99  Na  Na  Na  Na  4   2   2   Dad
Doe Jane    Interval_2  2/4/04  Na  Na  Na  Right-Handed    Na  Na  Na  Na
Doe Jane    Interval_2  2/4/04  5   6   3   Na  Na  Na  Na  Na 
Doe Jane    Interval_2  2/4/04  Na  Na  Na  Na  4   5   5   Mom
Smith   Joe Interval_1  3/1/01  5   1   7   Na  Na  Na  Na  Na
Smith   Joe Interval_1  3/1/01  Na  Na  Na  Left-Handed Na  Na  Na  Na
Smith   Joe Interval_1  3/1/01  Na  Na  Na  Na  8   8   2   Dad
Smith   Joe Interval_2  5/4/09  Na  Na  Na  Na  8   5   4   Dad
Smith   Joe Interval_2  5/4/09  7   2   8   Na  Na  Na  Na  Na
Smith   Joe Interval_2  5/4/09  Na  Na  Na  Left-Handed Na  Na  Na  Na", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: When I ran this script I got the following error: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `MFQ_1` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 9

Comment: You must have tried with your entire data.frame. If you try with the small example you provided, it works. The issue is that you want to summarise data by groups, but within each group, you likely have more than 1 `MFQ_1` value that is not == NA. Which not-NA `MFQ_1` value will you keep in those cases?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think it would have that, but in that case I would want the max value.

Comment: Wrap `i[i!="Na"]` in `max(...)` - `max(i[i!="Na"])`

Comment: The values are NA

Comment: The error was in the read.table portion: Error in read.table more columns than column names

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I was able to get the code to work :)

Comment: @KKhosra Please consider to accept this post as the answer if it works. See this link to learn how to do it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

First you need to replace your "Na" strings with explicit `NA` values

```
CTDB[CTDB == "Na"] <- NA
```

You also can't use `:` in the grouping function, so we'll list out the columns we want to group by. Then just wrap `na.omit()` with `first()` because `na.omit` alone isn't an aggregate function, and it doesn't tell `dplyr` how summarize.

```
CTDB %>% group_by(LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, INTERVAL, VISIT_DATE) %>% 
  summarize_all(funs(first(na.omit(.))))
```

Answer (score 0):

using base R:

```
df[df=="Na]=NA
aggregate(df,df[1:4],na.omit)[-(5:8)]
  LAST_NAME FIRST_NAME   INTERVAL VISIT_DATE MFQ_1 MFQ_2 MFQ_3   Handedness ARI_1 ARI_2 ARI_4 ARI_COMPLETED_BY
1       Doe       Jane Interval_1     1/1/99     4     6     2 Right-Handed     4     2     2              Dad
2       Doe       Jane Interval_2     2/4/04     5     6     3 Right-Handed     4     5     5              Mom
3     Smith        Joe Interval_1     3/1/01     5     1     7  Left-Handed     8     8     2              Dad
4     Smith        Joe Interval_2     5/4/09     7     2     8  Left-Handed     8     5     4              Dad
```